# Что за ключевое слово package в js?

Tags: javascript

Я заметил что js есть ключевое слово package, но я не нашел про это слово информацию. Что это за ключевое слово? Это что-то типа namespace как в php, c#? Или дайте мне документацию про это слово.

Comment: Оно зарезервировано: [Future reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#future_reserved_words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зарезервированное слово, но оно не используется.

> It is reserved, but not necessarily used (well, not at least of time of writing).
> The following are reserved as future keywords by the ECMAScript specification. They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers. (Note that for the moment Mozilla reserves these keywords only in strict mode code. Most other browsers reserve these keywords in all code, whether strict or not, so their use is very much non-portable. Mozilla will likely reserve these keywords in normal code in a future release, to conform to the specification and to be consistent with other browsers).

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords)